# How to determine which script is preventing link clicks to be processed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I took over the development responsibility of a PHP web application using a plethora of JS libraries and JQuery plugins.

Click event on any page using the default template is apparently trapped by some script which then

- always prevents selection of any text on the page (the opposite behavior is a requirement)
- prevents sidebar links (with href="#")  from being triggered via the associated js/jQuery click function (for example: $('a.someclass').click(function(e) { ... ).

I have searched the entire project for any files which might be containing "preventDefault()" but couldn't find anything?

What should I do to find out which one of the scripts is causing the issue?

Is the only way of finding out disabling all scripts and then activating one by one as I test the functionality along the way (which, in my case take weeks, therefore hoping to be advised of a shorter way)?

Comment: stopPropagation(); could be something to look for as well

Comment: Also maybe search for the id / class names found in the sidebar. May be a universal rule in a file targeting the elements within the sidebar by the sidebar's ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Chrome developer tools can help you to figure out, which `click` listener is the right you need, so open your page into the Google Chrome Browser, then right click (for Windows) or double tap in the touchpad (Mac Os), then:

1. Select `Inspect` option in the context menu
2. It will open a window with the developer tools, then select the `Sources` tab
3. Then in the right panel you will see some accordion panels go to the `Event Listeners Breakpoints`
4. Go open the `Mouse` panel and mark `click` and `mousedown` events
5. Refresh the page and start clicking in the items to figure out which event you need, you will notice that a light silver overlay layer will appear in the site, so you can go to next listener until you find what you looking for.

you can find more information at the [Google Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints)